# How to request source code?

Tags: phd, code, economics

During literature review for my research proposal, I have come across a professor who has published several papers in my field, some closely related to the topic of my own research. In a series of papers he uses a specific model, expanding on and extending it in each paper. In my work, I want to use the same kind of model (evolutionary) and I would love to see the source code, both to better understand and replicate the results and because it would tremendously help me in getting started. Unfortunately, I could not find it anywhere and it is not published with any of the papers.

I am wondering if and how I should ask for the code and have three related questions:

1. Is it common to just email and ask for the source code or would that be considered somehow inappropriate? I might well end up applying to the university that professor is teaching at, so I don't want to leave a bad impression.
2. Who is the appropriate person to contact? All of the papers on the model have been published by by the professor and the same two co-authors, some with additional co-authors. Should I email the professor himself, one of the co-authors, or all of them?
3. How much detail about my own research should I include in my email? Just what's sufficient to justify the request or more, possibly a draft of the proposal?

Comment: So, in brief, you want all his work and you give nothing?

Comment: I think the model source code is hardly **all** the work, considerably more effort probably went into other parts of the papers.

Comment: @Solar Mike : He did not mention that he would "give nothing", either. Moreover, whether or not "something" should be "given" depends, at least I think, _solely_ upon the other person. If they want something in return, then that must be honored. But if they are willing to give it for gratis, that too is their right.

Comment: @SolarMike It's sad to see that that is the mindset of a researcher these days. I mean, the code *is* part the paper, so what OP is asking for is something that should have actually been published with it. Fortunately, there has [been some efforts on that front](https://paperswithcode.com/)

Comment: @SolarMike In my opinion, a paper based on code that does not contain such code (model, algorithm or whatever else) its incomplete. Is a psycology experiment paper valid without the data? Is a global temperature paper valid without the data? I hope not (even if there are many). I think a model/algorithm paper should not be valid without the code to reproduce the paper results. Research is (and should be open).

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: I have done this *several* times. Sometimes you get a reply and code, sometimes you do not. I have received such request too and I always try to give the code (if its not already public). If you are a student however, I **strongly** encourage you to cc your supervisor.

Comment: @SolarMike At a bare minimum, he'd be giving the author of the original paper a citation. It's not much, but it's not nothing, either.

Comment: @user4052054 I have some interest in supersonic flow, do you think NASA will give me their results & codes?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes! NASA has tons of open-source code available at https://code.nasa.gov. Check out the projects called [Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) Utility Software Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cfdutilities/) ("applicable to all flight regimes-subsonic, transonic, supersonic, and hypersonic"), [TLNS3D](https://github.com/nasa/TLNS3D) ("efficient [...] for solving transonic viscous flows"), [CFL3D](https://github.com/NASA/CFL3D), and [Geometry Manipulation Protocol](https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/opensource/projects/gmp/).

Comment: @AnderBiguri Why cc the supervisor? I would not do that (profs mailbox is already overflowing, and I am not 12 years old), although I might eventually have a better chance of getting an answer. Anything else?

Comment: @Karl because of the mistrust some people has for students. A random student asking for code may have been given the task to code that (e.g. for learning purposes) and may be trying to circumvent work that the supervisor requires. When I was a student and would send emails like that I had a couple of people reply "please send me the email again with your supervisor cc'd".

Comment: @Karl Sometimes it helps to get the supervisor to send a confirming email - obviously the students you have met are all perfect, some of us are not so lucky...

Comment: @Vectornaut I think that might be just the common stuff... I know of code that was used on one plane that many people around the world want but it is commercial and kept under lock and key...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Whether common or not, it is acceptable to ask. Ask the main professor, who may pass on the request to a co-author.

I'd suggest that you only give a small amount of detail in the initial request but offer to say more if you like. But don't flood the professor in the initial request. Mention that you have a draft, but don't send it. And you can certainly mention that you are interested in applying to the university.

What happens next depends on the nature of the reply. Perhaps they will want to help you, but other outcomes are possible.

Comment: This is perfect; direct, honest and non-evasive.

Comment: My only amendment to this would be that it might be better to ask the author who is listed as a *corresponding author* on the paper - they can pass on the request as appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it common to just email and ask for the source code or would that be considered somehow inappropriate?

It's not improper to ask. Consider some core values of the scientific world:

- **Reproducibility:** for research to be truly valid, others should be able to reproduce it. This is why publishing source code is encouraged.
- **Standing on the shoulders of giants:** science is all about building on each others' achievements. My discovery may help you and your discovery may help me. It's not a zero-sum game.

> Who is the appropriate person to contact? All of the papers on the model have been published by by the professor and the same two co-authors, some with additional co-authors. Should I email the professor himself, one of the co-authors, or all of them?

Now, what is the best way to ask? You can email directly, but it would be nice if you can find a mutual acquaintance that can introduce you.

Is there anyone in your department (maybe your supervisor) that has met this professor before? One of the reasons scientists go to conferences is to build these networks. Or maybe someone in your department has co-authored something with the professor or his co-authors; go through the professor's publication list and look for familiar names.

Ask your supervisor if they know anything about the professor that's relevant. It's part of the supervisor's role to know the field and use it to advise you.

In the end, who you contact is a bit opportunistic. If you have a good connection to one particular person, start there.

> How much detail about my own research should I include in my email? Just what's sufficient to justify the request or more, possibly a draft of the proposal?

I would keep it reasonably short. Enough to justify the request, certainly. But in general you don't share draft proposals until you've gained whatever grant you're applying for.